# how to Add sub menu to dropdown menu

Tags: html, css, templates, drop-down-menu, submenu

I want to add sub-menu to this drop down function,but i have little knowledge of css , i am not getting how to do this. i want the sub-menu open to right side when cursor is placed on it Here is the css and html relating to it

**CSS**

```
ul.dark_menu {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 5px 1px;
    font-family:'Segoe UI Light', 'Open Sans', Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 200;
    font-size: 16px;
    letter-spacing: 0.01em;
    font-smooth: always;
    color: #000000;
    line-height: 15px;
    margin: auto;
    width: 1018px;
    position: relative;
    background: #2B5797;
}
/* Blog johanes djogzs.blogspot.com */
 ul.dark_menu:after {
    content:"";
    clear: both;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
}
ul.dark_menu li {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    margin: 1px;
}
/* Blog johanes djogzs.blogspot.com */
 ul.dark_menu li a, ul.dark_menu li a:link {
    color: #fafafa;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    padding: 8px 26px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.2s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 0.2s ease;
    transition: all 0.2s ease;
}
/* Blog johanes djogzs.blogspot.com */
 ul.dark_menu li a:hover {
    color: #fafafa;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
/* Blog johanes djogzs.blogspot.com */
 ul.dark_menu li a.selected {
    border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
ul.dark_menu li a.selected, ul.dark_menu li a:active {
    color: #fafafa;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
ul.dark_menu li ul {
    display: none;
}
/* Blog johanes djogzs.blogspot.com */
 ul.dark_menu li ul:before {
    content:" ";
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    z-index: 1500;
    left: 0;
    top: -10px;
    height: 10px;
    width: 100%;
}
ul.dark_menu li ul {
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    top:55px;
}
ul.dark_menu li:hover ul {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    z-index: 1000;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    left: 0;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 5px 5px;
    top: 37px;
    padding: 5px 0;
    list-style: none;
    background: #fff;
}
/* Blog johanes djogzs.blogspot.com */
 ul.dark_menu li ul li {
    float: none;
    margin:0px;
}
ul.dark_menu li ul li:first-child {
    margin:0px;
    border-top: 0 none;
}
ul.dark_menu li ul li:last-child {
    border-bottom: 0 none;
}
/* Blog johanes djogzs.blogspot.com */
 ul.dark_menu[data-role="dropdown"] > a::before {
    position: absolute;
    content:"^";
    display: block;
    font-size: 15px;
    left: 100%;
    margin-left: -20px;
    top: 10px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(180deg);
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}
ul.dark_menu li ul li a, ul.dark_menu li ul li a:link {
    color: #222;
    display: block;
    background: transparent none;
    padding: 10px 25px 10px 25px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
ul.dark_menu li ul li a:hover {
    background:#2D89EF;
    -moz-transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out;
    color:#fff;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out;
}
/* Blog johanes djogzs.blogspot.com */
 .menujohanes {
    position:relative;
}
#search input[type="text"]:hover {
    width:848px;
}
#search input[type="text"] {
    background: #fff url("http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-uYZni0pIn-E/T-xY2vVu_-I/AAAAAAAACUY/ZMfR3_BvRFE/s1600/SEARCH_32x32-32.png")no-repeat center left;
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #222;
    width: 0px;
    padding: 10px 0px 11px 35px;
    z-index: 9;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    margin-bottom: -1px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right:27px;
}
#main4, #main5, #main6 {
    width: 303px;
    list-style-type: none;
    float: left;
    margin: 10px;
}
.main3 {
    width:305px;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding-top: 10px;
    float: left;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    height:12px;
    background: #474747;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background-color: #000;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class='menujohanes'>
        <ul class='dark_menu'>
          <li>
            <a class='selected' expr:href='data:blog.homepageUrl' title='Home'>
              Home
            </a>
          </li>

       <li data-role='dropdown'>
            <a href='#'>
              Categories
            </a>
            <ul>
                 <li>
                    <a href='#'>
                    Lorem ipsum
                    </a>
                </li>

               <li>
                <a href='#'>
                  Lorem ipsum
                </a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href='#'>
                  Lorem ipsum
                </a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href='#'>
                  Lorem ipsum
                </a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href='#'>
                  Download
                </a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href='#'>
                  Lorem ipsum
                </a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <form action='/search' id='search' method='get'>
          <input name='q' placeholder='Search Somethings..' size='40' type='text'/>
        </form>
      </div>
```

Please help as I did search over Google for it but didn't understood how to include sub-menu into this.

Thanks

Comment: So you want a dropdown menu, on selecting any option you want other dropdown menu to open aside ??

Comment: Can you please use [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) to show your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
 <li class='sub'>
     <a href='#'>Lorem ipsum </a>
        <ul>
           <li>
             <a href='#'>
                sub-item 1
               </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
 </li>
```

and in css add this

```
 li.sub ul {
display:none;
position: absolute; left: 100%; top:0;}

li.sub:hover ul{
display: block;}
```

For creating new sub menus just add class='sub' to the < li> and add new < ul> below it as a child .
Example: http://jsfiddle.net/6kDG8/2/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ul.dark_menu li ul li ul li { display: none; }
ul.dark_menu li ul li:hover ul li { display: block;}
ul.dark_menu li ul li:hover ul { left: 100%; top: 0; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tkbub/1/

Answer (score 0):

```css
/*Strip the ul of padding and list styling*/
ul {
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    position: absolute;
}
/*Create a horizontal list with spacing*/
li {
    display:inline-block;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 1px;
}
/*Strip the ul of padding and list styling*/
ul {
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    position: absolute;
}
/*Create a horizontal list with spacing*/
li {
    display:inline-block;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 1px;
}
/*Style for menu links*/
li a {
    display:block;
    min-width:140px;
    height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 50px;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    color: #fff;
    background: #2f3036;
    text-decoration: none;
}
/*Hover state for top level links*/
li:hover a {
    background: #19c589;
}
/*Style for dropdown links*/
li:hover ul a {
    background: #f3f3f3;
    color: #2f3036;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
}
/*Hover state for dropdown links*/
li:hover ul a:hover {
    background: #19c589;
    color: #fff;
}
/*Hide dropdown links until they are needed*/
li ul {
    display: none;
}
/*Make dropdown links vertical*/
li ul li {
    display: block;
    float: none;
}
/*Prevent text wrapping*/
li ul li a {
    width: auto;
    min-width: 100px;
    padding: 0 20px;
}
/*Display the dropdown on hover*/
ul li a:hover + .hidden, .hidden:hover {
    display: block;
}
/*Style 'show menu' label button and hide it by default*/
.show-menu {
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    background: #19c589;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px 0;
    display: none;
}
/*Hide checkbox*/
input[type=checkbox]{
    display: none;
}
/*Show menu when invisible checkbox is checked*/
input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ #menu{
    display: block;
}
/*Responsive Styles*/
@media screen and (max-width : 760px){
    /*Make dropdown links appear inline*/
    ul {
        position: static;
        display: none;
    }
    /*Create vertical spacing*/
    li {
        margin-bottom: 1px;
    }
    /*Make all menu links full width*/
    ul li, li a {
        width: 100%;
    }
    /*Display 'show menu' link*/
    .show-menu {
        display:block;
    }
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>CSS Only Navigation Menu</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <ul id="menu">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">About ￬</a>
            <ul class="hidden">
                <li><a href="#">Who We Are</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">What We Do</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Portfolio ￬</a>
            <ul class="hidden">
                <li><a href="#">Photography</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Web & User Interface Design</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Illustration</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</body>
</html
```

Comment: Can you add an explanation of what the code does and how this relates tot he OP question.