# How to convert unordered list into <select> dropdown using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

How do I convert an unordered list in this format

```html
<ul class="selectdropdown">
    <li><a href="one.html" target="_blank">one</a></li>
    <li><a href="two.html" target="_blank">two</a></li>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="twoOne.html" target="_blank">two One</a></li>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="twoOneOne.html" target="_blank">two One One</a></li>
        </ul>
        <li><a href="twoTwo.html" target="_blank">twoTwo</a></li>
    </ul>
    <li><a href="three.html" target="_blank">three</a></li>
    <li><a href="four.html" target="_blank">four</a></li>
    <li><a href="five.html" target="_blank">five</a></li>
    <li><a href="six.html" target="_blank">six</a></li>
    <li><a href="seven.html" target="_blank">seven</a></li>
</ul>
```

I want to convert this structure into `<select>` structure

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1897129/how-to-convert-unordered-list-into-nicely-styled-select-dropdown-using-jquery

This might help

Comment: but that answer give only 1 level of sub part i want 2 level of sub menu

Comment: In a `select` element (pure HTML) you can't have clickable tree structure afaik. You can define `optgroup`s, but the group name does not have a value. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11168257 for a jQuery solution.

Comment: I am unsure about what you exactly want: you want to **transform** your HTML with <select>, or you want that it **behaves** like a <select> tag with hierarchical content ?

Answer (score 0):

jquery code

```
  jQuery('.selectdropdown li a').each(function() {
        var el = jQuery(this);
        jQuery('<option />', {
            "value"   : el.attr('href'),
            "text"    : el.text()
        }).appendTo('#top select');
    });
    if (jQuery('.selectdropdown li a').length < 1) jQuery('#top').hide();

    jQuery('#top').find('select').change(function() {
        window.location = jQuery(this).find('option:selected').val();
    });
```

HTML

```
<div id="top">
<select></select>
</div>
```

Here Is fiddle [Fiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/lvtrvd/y97bzsgv/)

Answer (score 0):

Try Something like  This:

```css
ul.dark_menu {
list-style: none;
padding: 5px 1px;
font-family: 'Segoe UI Light', 'Open Sans', Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-weight: 200;
font-size: 16px;
letter-spacing: 0.01em;
font-smooth: always;
color: #000000;
line-height: 15px;
margin: auto;
width: 1018px;
position: relative;
background: #2B5797;
}/* Blog johanes djogzs.blogspot.com */
ul.dark_menu:after {
content: "";
clear: both;
display: block;
overflow: hidden;
visibility: hidden;
width: 0;
height: 0;}
ul.dark_menu li {
float: left;
position: relative;
margin: 1px;}
/* Blog johanes djogzs.blogspot.com */
ul.dark_menu li a, ul.dark_menu li a:link {
color: #fafafa;
text-decoration: none;
display: block;
padding: 8px 26px;
-webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
-moz-transition: all 0.2s ease;
-o-transition: all 0.2s ease;
-ms-transition: all 0.2s ease;
transition: all 0.2s ease;
}/* Blog johanes djogzs.blogspot.com */
ul.dark_menu li a:hover {
color: #fafafa;
-webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
-moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
-o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
transition: all 0.5s ease;
}/* Blog johanes djogzs.blogspot.com */
ul.dark_menu li a.selected {
border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
text-transform: uppercase;
margin-left: 10px;
}
ul.dark_menu li a.selected, ul.dark_menu li a:active {
color: #fafafa;
-webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
-moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
-o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
transition: all 0.5s ease;}
ul.dark_menu li ul {
display: none;
}/* Blog johanes djogzs.blogspot.com */
ul.dark_menu li ul:before {
content: " ";
position: absolute;
display: block;
z-index: 1500;
left: 0;
top: -10px;
height: 10px;
width: 100%;}
ul.dark_menu li ul {-webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
-moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
-o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
transition: all 0.5s ease;top:55px;}
ul.dark_menu li:hover ul {
position: absolute;
display: block;
z-index: 1000;
box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
left: 0;border-radius: 0px 0px 5px 5px;
top: 37px;
padding: 5px 0;
list-style: none;
background: #fff;
}/* Blog johanes djogzs.blogspot.com */
ul.dark_menu li ul li {
float: none;
margin:0px;}
ul.dark_menu li ul li:first-child {
margin:0px;
border-top: 0 none;}
ul.dark_menu li ul li:last-child {
border-bottom: 0 none;
}/* Blog johanes djogzs.blogspot.com */
ul.dark_menu [data-role="dropdown"] > a::before {
position: absolute;
content: "^";
display: block;
font-size: 15px;
left: 100%;
margin-left: -20px;
top: 10px;
-webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
-moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
-ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
-o-transform: rotate(180deg);
transform: rotate(180deg);
}
ul.dark_menu li ul li a, ul.dark_menu li ul li a:link {
color: #222;
display: block;
background: transparent none;
padding: 10px 25px 10px 25px;
white-space: nowrap;}
ul.dark_menu li ul li a:hover {
background:#2D89EF;-moz-transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out;color:#fff;
-webkit-transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out;
}/* Blog johanes djogzs.blogspot.com */
.menujohanes{position:relative;}
#search input[type="text"]:hover {width:848px;}
#search input[type="text"] {
background: #fff url("http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-uYZni0pIn-E/T-xY2vVu_-I/AAAAAAAACUY/ZMfR3_BvRFE/s1600/SEARCH_32x32-32.png")no-repeat center left;
font-size: 13px;
color: #222;
width: 0px;
padding: 10px 0px 11px 35px;
z-index: 9;
border: 1px solid #fff;
-webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
margin-bottom: -1px;
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
right:27px;}
#main4, #main5, #main6 {
width: 303px;
list-style-type: none;
float: left;
margin: 10px;}
.main3 {width:305px;
list-style-type: none;
padding-top: 10px;
float: left;}
::-webkit-scrollbar {
height:12px;
background: #474747;}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
background-color: #000;
}
 li#sub ul {
    display:none;
 position: absolute; left: 100%; top:0;
}
li#sub:hover ul{
display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class='menujohanes'>
        <ul class='dark_menu'>
       

       <li data-role='dropdown'>
            <a href='#'>
              Categories
            </a>
            <ul>
                 <li id='sub'>
                    <a href='#'>
                    Lorem ipsum
                    </a>
                     <ul>
                         <li>
            <a href='#'>
              Categories2
                             </a></li><li>
            <a href='#'>
              Categories3
                             </a></li>
                     </ul>
                         
                </li>

               <li>
                <a href='#'>
                  Lorem ipsum
                </a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href='#'>
                  Lorem ipsum
                </a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href='#'>
                  Lorem ipsum
                </a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href='#'>
                  Download
                </a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href='#'>
                  Lorem ipsum
                </a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <form action='/search' id='search' method='get'>
          <input name='q' placeholder='Search Somethings..' size='40' type='text'/>
        </form>
      </div>
```

Got Help From [Here:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17857276/how-to-add-sub-menu-to-dropdown-menu)

Comment: This doesn't do at all what the OP asked.

Answer (score 0):

I've recently created something like this, check it out:

```html
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#dropdownSelect").click(function(){
        $("#multiSelect").slideToggle("fast");
    });
});
</script>
<style>
#dropdownSelect{
    cursor:pointer;
    color:#000;
    padding:7px 20px;
    width:400px;
}
#dropdownSelect p{
  background: #eee;
  width:400px;
}
#multiSelect{
    display:none;
    height:150px;
    background:#ccc;
    z-index:1;
    overflow:auto;
    position:absolute;
    width:400px;
    color:#000;
    top:60px;
    left:28px;
}
#multiSelect ul {
    list-style:none;
    text-decoration:none;
    padding-left:10px;
}
#multiSelect li>ul{
    list-style:none;
    text-decoration:none;
    padding-left: 10px;
  cursor:pointer;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<dl>
    <dt id="dropdownSelect">
        <p>Choose</p>
    </dt>
    <dd>
        <div id="multiSelect">
            <ul>
                <li>Link-1</li>
                <li>Link-2</li>
                <li>Link-3</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </dd>
</dl>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is this really handy plugin where it will turn your select element into an unordered list for you. I use it all the time because it's pretty sexy and fast.

http://code.octopuscreative.com/fancyselect/